# How do you get network protocol enabled details on Network Adapters in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, wmi, network-protocols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you retrieve a list of bound protocols to a network adapter? (in PowerShell or any language )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248714/how-do-you-retrieve-a-list-of-bound-protocols-to-a-network-adapter-in-powershel)

For a specific network adapter, how can I list what the protocols are? I'd like to enumerate each, and find their enabled/disabled status. In the Windows UI, this is shown as a checkmark. Protocols may include

- Client for Microsoft Networks
- Qos Packet Scheduler
- Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IPv6)
- Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)

Does anybody know how to get this?

Answer (score 0):

This question seems very similar you what you want to achieve.

[Detect If IPv6 is Enabled on Windows Machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083412/detect-if-ipv6-is-enabled-on-windows-machines)

There are many different methods listed.