# How do you retrieve a list of bound protocols to a network adapter? (in PowerShell or any language )

Tags: windows, networking, powershell

So in the windows UI, if you right click on a network adapter you see a properties page that has a section labeled "This connection uses the following items"
and in this property page is a list of items with a check box beside them such as

- Client for Microsoft Networks
- Qos Packet Scheduler
- IP Protocol Version 6

etc

I want to programatically get this list, and know whether that protocol is bound (the checkbox) is checked.

i can't seem to find any WMI class that shows this, and the closest i've seen is a primitive come interface INetCfg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not native PowerShell but there is a tool called nvsbind.exe that was written by someone on the hyper-v team so you can do these operations in Server Core.
You can find here

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/nvspbind

Comment: I wish we have code shown here. Will help me a lot at this time :)